# Can I make CNTK detect overfitting?

Tags: cntk

CNTK only stops after maxEpochs is reached, and then runs test. Is there a way to make it run test after each epoch to check if it is severely overfitting?

Comment: Hi, LOST. Were You able to solve your problem in the end? I'm just experiencing the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

How about run until end, and then validate at different epochs? You may refer to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Do-early-stopping).

Comment: I am playing with models, and want to detect early overfitting so that trial-and-error loop iterations would take less time.

Comment: You can check a validation minibatch any time you'd like during the training process with trainer.eval_minibatch(validation_minibatch)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. There are the technical issues running an test on the test data after each epoch.(I cannot comment on that) But this is not the important issues! The second issue is that you are polluting the test dataset if you are using it several times. If you are using, you test data as a stop criteria you are fitting you data to the test data set!   Therefore, only use you test data on time, and don’t use the test data as for any kind of training.